# jQuery plugin not being called on window resize

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, window-resize

On a web page I have many tables all with class='gsresponsive'.

I have a jQuery plugin which I can point at multiple tables with class gsresponsive and wrap them in 2 divs like below. The 2nd div width will be set to 100% if screen width > 767px else the width will be set to 1024px (unless overridden). When the page loads, the appropriate width will be applied, but I want the plugin to be called again on window resize. But this is not happening.

Why won't my plugin re-run on window risize and apply the new width when the screen goes either side of 767px?

```
<div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="width:100%"> <!-- screen size dependant-->
        <table> ....</table>
    </div>
<div>
```

My plugin is called like this ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table.gsresponsive").gstable();
});
```

My plugin looks like this ...

```
(function($) {
$.fn.extend({
    gstable: function(options) {

        //Define default options.
        var defaults = {
            scrsplit : 767,         //Modify table when screen gets to this size.
            tblwidth : "1024px"     //Default table width when on a small screen (screen width < scrsplit).
        }

        var o = $.extend(defaults, options);
        var $obj = $(this);

        return this.each(function() {

            $obj.wrap("<div class=\"table-wrapper\" style=\"overflow:auto;\" />");
            if ($(window).width() < o.scrsplit){
                $obj.wrap("<div style=\"width:"+o.tblwidth+"\" />");
            } else {
                $obj.wrap("<div style=\"width:100%;\" />");
            }

            $(window).load(updateOvalTables);
            $(window).bind("resize", updateOvalTables);

        });

        var switched = false;
        var updateOvalTables = function() {
            alert('updating');
            if (($(window).width() < o.scrsplit) && !switched ){
                switched = true;
                splitOvalTable($obj);
                //return true;
            }   else if (switched && ($(window).width() > o.scrsplit)) {
                switched = false;
                unsplitOvalTable($obj);
            }
        };

        function splitOvalTable(elem) {
            elem.parent().css("width", o.tblwidth);   
        }

        function unsplitOvalTable(original) {
            elem.parent().css("width", "100%");   
        }

    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: never attempted it but you could try doing the same initialisation inside a `$(window).resize(function()`, e.g. `$(window).resize(function() { $("table.gsresponsive").gstable(); });` however I don't know if that will definitely solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function expression, i.e. the variable `updateOvalTables` is declared after the `$.each` function. It still gets hoisted, but in the `.each` loop `updateOvalTables` is undefined. You're also declaring the variables after the `return` statement, which is a bit late.

So this:

```
$(document).on('click', foo);

var foo = function() { alert(); }
```

would'nt work as `foo` is not defined yet, but this :

```
var foo = function() { alert(); }

$(document).on('click', foo);
```

works because `foo` is defined!

So move the function expression above the `$.each` loop (or change it to a function declaration):

```
(function($) {
$.fn.extend({
    gstable: function(options) {

        //Define default options.
        var defaults = {
            scrsplit : 767,         //Modify table when screen gets to this size.
            tblwidth : "1024px"     //Default table width when on a small screen (screen width < scrsplit).
        }

        var o                = $.extend(defaults, options),
            $obj             = $(this),
            switched         = false;
            updateOvalTables = function() {
                alert('updating');
                if (($(window).width() < o.scrsplit) && !switched ){
                    switched = true;
                    splitOvalTable($obj);
                    //return true;
                }   else if (switched && ($(window).width() > o.scrsplit)) {
                    switched = false;
                    unsplitOvalTable($obj);
                }    
            };

        return this.each(function() {

            $obj.wrap("<div class=\"table-wrapper\" style=\"overflow:auto;\" />");
            if ($(window).width() < o.scrsplit){
                $obj.wrap("<div style=\"width:"+o.tblwidth+"\" />");
            } else {
                $obj.wrap("<div style=\"width:100%;\" />");
            }

            $(window).load(updateOvalTables);
            $(window).bind("resize", updateOvalTables);
        });

        function splitOvalTable(elem) {
            elem.parent().css("width", o.tblwidth);   
        }

        function unsplitOvalTable(original) {
            elem.parent().css("width", "100%");   
        }

    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I was nearly there ;o) That did the job :o) Thanks adeneo.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a separate resize function?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("window inizialized");
    $("table.gsresponsive").gstable();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        console.log("resize event fired");
        $("table.gsresponsive").gstable().updateOvalTables();
    });
  });
```